# How to optimize my javascript slider loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been coding up a little responsive image slider to display my wedding photos using [responsiveslides.js](http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/) and a little script to deal with vertical images (it sets a max-height based on the browser viewport). You can see it at http://johnandalex.us/photos It's finally working pretty much how I want it to, with 2 exceptions:

1. The pics show up and then resize after a delay (when the browser window is smaller than the full size of the picture)
2. The prev/next arrows don't show up until the pics are completely loaded (which takes a while, especially on slower connections because there are over 100 images)

Any ideas for how to improve on these 2 items? I'm totally comfortable with HTML and CSS, but am a complete novice when it comes to JS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would hide the slideshow container until $(document).ready fires, then show the control.  You can display a loader animated gif while the page is loading up.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of how you could achieve this effect:

First you need to specify display:none on the UL that contains your slideshow:

```
<ul class="rslides rslides1" style="display:none;">
```

Next, show the slideshow container on document ready and init the plugin as you already have done:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".rslides").show();

    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        speed: 700,
        timeout: 3000,
        nav: true
    });
  });
```

Comment: How would I go about incorporating this with the current slideshow plugin?

Comment: Ok, I added in that code, but I'm not sure it's working right still. Why do the arrows take so long to load, even though their background square shows immediately? Also, where would a loading animation come into the picture?

Comment: I changed the document.ready to window.load and it looks like I'm getting the effect I was looking for. Is this ok to do? Would you just set a loading spinner as the page background in this case?

Comment: Yep, you would have to code in a spinner yourself.  Once the document/ready fired you would hide that element before you showed the slideshow.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it all working now. Take a look. I'm displaying a loading GIF on document.ready and hiding it on window.load. Is that a sound way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should always set a height and a width to images when possible.